# How to print a wikipedia page with the style retained?

Tags: css, printing, media-queries, wikipedia

I would like to print a wikipedia page as-is with the header and the sidebar. By default, when you print them, articles are styled specially for the print medium. I am making material for a programming course and I specifically DON'T want that. checking `$('[media]')` returns several style and link elements but all are set with `media="all"`.

Where is the stripped down styling coming from and how do I make it not apply?

Comment: Why don't you just do a PrtScn, paste it in paint, and print that?

Comment: @techjunkie.css right and if the page has 50 "pages" ...

Comment: There are probably inline media queries in some of those CSS files that specify screen/print-only styles.

Comment: They're using `@media print` withing their stylesheet.

Comment: try these: http://www.printpunk.com/, http://www.oldapps.com/fast_stone_capture.php

Comment: There are also various browser extensions that will capture an entire webpage and save it as a JPG, their may be some oddities with JS-positioned elements, but for the most part, they can be pretty handy. (e.g, for chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cjjghkapdciaiogkeofggpblmbbnjinn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the source of an article page, you'll notice there's a class `.noprint` which is simply:

```
 display: none;
```

In the external stylesheet itself (`bits.wikimedia.org/en.wikipedia.org/load.php? ...`), they use an `@media print` directive:

```
@media print{  a.stub,a.new{color:#ba0000;text-decoration:none}...
...etc...
```

If you use Firebug (or similar), you should be able to remove the `.noprint` and classes and related CSS to get round the styling.

Comment: Ah yes, `$('.noprint').removeClass('noprint')` worked great. Thanks!

Comment: Ouch, actually, no it didn't flow content made the left-hand print after the content. Might not be any good way around this except export to image

Comment: The `@media print` directive also applies to some other elements and classes, take a look at the source and search for **'@media print'**